# Force video to open in Youtube app on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube

I have a mobile website that links to a youtube video. On Android, clicking on this link brings up a dialog asking the user to "Complete action using" their browser or the Youtube app.

Is there a way to bypass this screen and just play the video in the Youtube app? (For example with a youtube:// URL.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's how you can do that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + id));
startActivity(intent);
```

The id is the identifier after the questionmark in the url. For example: youtube.com/watch?v=*ID*

Another way is:

```
Intent videoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
videoIntent.setData(url);
videoIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.youtube", "com.google.android.youtube.WatchActivity");
startActivity(videoIntent);
```

......

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the vnd.youtube:// URL tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: Is there a way to check (from a mobile website) whether a device can open vnd.youtube:// URLs? I would like my site to open vnd.youtube:// URL for Android and a regular http://youtube.com/watch? link for iOS.

Comment: At least none that I know, sorry

Comment: Do you know the link for youtube channels ?

Comment: For my case, 1st way by id works well, but 2nd way does not.

Comment: Thanks this works. I am just wondering what will happen if use does not have YouTube app?

Answer (score 8):

The best way

```
try {

     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + id));
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     startActivity(intent);

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

    // youtube is not installed.Will be opened in other available apps

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://youtube.com/watch?v=" + id));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your solution but I got "cannot resolve symbol content". Can you please explain to me what is this content?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use a JavaScript redirection like the following:

```
window.location = "vnd.youtube://the.youtube.video.url";
```

More comprehensively:

```
if( /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent ) ) {
    // If the user is using an Android device.
    setTimeout(function () { window.location = "market://details?id=com.google.android.youtube"; }, 25);
    window.location = "vnd.youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yourVideoId";
}
```

If Youtube app is disabled, the timeout function will redirect you to the youtube app on the play store to let you enable the app. The second redirect will pop up and play the youtube video on Android Youtube app.

If you are already switched to the YouTube app within the timeout interval, the timeout function will not be called and you are not switched to the play store but stay in the YouTube app.