# Open youtube video embedded in webview in youtube player

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I have webview and some html + youtube video loaded. Is it possible to open youtube videos in youtube app instead of webview?

Comment: Try the accepted answer at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11114413/867591

Comment: @JaVAndroid I have url to some news article with youtube video embedded. So the question is - if I click on this player, how can I force it to play in youtube app, not in the same webview

Comment: Try this:
String videoId = "dh6hE5uPcRM";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:"+videoId)); 
intent.putExtra("VIDEO_ID", videoId); 
startActivity(intent);

Comment: @JaVAndroid but is it possible to catch a click on youtube player? So then I could open in a new intent

Comment: I'm not sure on that...haven't tried capturing an event from the player yet...well worth a try :)

Comment: @Roman did you get this solved in the end?

Comment: @AndrewWeir what happerns is that some videos are handled by Youtube app, some open in browser. Seems like depends on link structure. We agreed with the clients to leave this headache for some future update :)