# Launch Youtube App from mobile website on Android/iOS

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios, youtube

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqX4ohZo8AM">Play Video</a>
```

How can I force that link to open the YouTube app on an iOS or Android device if one exists with Javascript or native HTML?

Currently it will link to the youtube mobile site then try to launch the App from there when I tried it on Android.

Comment: You are posting this link and want your users to see it in the app?

Comment: yes.. when they click/touch that link the YouTube app on their device should open (if it is installed). The link in an example.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will fix it for you.

[Force video to open in Youtube app on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114341/force-video-to-open-in-youtube-app-on-android)

I guess that makes this a dup.

Comment: But is that JavaScript? That looks suspiciously like Java, I need this to work on a website, not within another app. 

Where do I apply the code links in that question?

Comment: You know you are right. It might be java. As far as I know forcing an app to open from a standard link would be a breach of security. I am pretty sure that using the desktop link instead of mobile typically opens the app. However, this is ultimately a user setting.

Comment: If it were breach of security, they wouldn't allow you to do it from other apps. I think the actual reason is they just don't have the infrastructure set up for it yet. But yes, for now, desktop links open in the app.