# Nativescript openUrl

Tags: facebook, youtube, instagram, url-scheme, nativescript

Anyone know how to launch native apps on iOS from a NativeScript app using the app URL schemes? These URLs are returning `false` and not launching the apps as expected when using `openUrl` via the NativeScript `utils` module.

1. Facebook - `openUrlModule.openUrl("fb://profile/<profileid>")`
2. Instagram - `openUrlModule.openUrl("instagram://app")`
3. Youtube - `openUrlModule.openUrl("youtube://app")`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this has been discussed in the NativeScript Slack Channel, capturing answer here for others that have similar challenges.

In iOS 9, Apple requires apps to whitelist the URL schemes they are allowed to open. This requires an additional key in the Info.plist.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>{SCHEME NAMES HERE}</string>
    <string>fb</string>
    <string>...</string>
</array>
```

In NativeScript, add this key to the Info.plist in the `app > App_Resources > iOS` directory (if you're using the CLI).

(If you're using Telerik AppBuilder, modify the Info.plist by right-clicking on your project name in the project explorer and then `Edit Configuration > iOS Info.plist`. This generates a Info.plist with all default settings in the App_Resources directory.)

See this StackOverflow post for more detail on the new key in iOS9:
[iOS 9 not opening Instagram app with URL SCHEME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Works like a Charm! Thanks @Todd

Answer (score 0):

Code seems the same
(Android)
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/1ad23a3a78bbf95e2b89a82d9473498ee0dda350/tns-core-modules/utils/utils.android.ts#L299

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11114413/1368333

Although they use a different url scheme it seems