# how to make playlist of youtube links in my activity in android?

Tags: android, youtube

I have some YouTube links and I want to make a list like the playlist that exists in youtube such that a screen shot from the video automatically appear and when the user click on the link it opens the youtube app 
How can I do it ?

thanks in advance

Comment: look into YouTube API for getting screenshots, and firing intents in Android Developer guides to launch another application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the YouTube thumbnails, you can use the techniques outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api) to grab the url of several auto-generated thumbnails, and using an image library like [`Picasso`](http://square.github.io/picasso/) it is straightforward to load the image into an `ImageView`:

```
private static final String EXAMPLE_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID = fMOqfsBzqLU;

public static String getYouTubeThumbnailUrl(String videoId) {
    return "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId + "/0.jpg";
}

//To use...

Picasso.with(context).load(getYouTubeThumbnailUrl(EXAMPLE_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID)).into(imageView);
```

Use a `RecyclerView` or `ListView` to display the images, and set an `onClickListener()` to the `ImageView` that links to the video on YouTube:

```
public static String getYouTubeVideoLink(String videoId) {
    return "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoId;
}

//To launch the video in the defaul browser...

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(getYouTubeVideoLink(EXAMPLE_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID)));
startActivity(i);
```

**Edit:** To open the video in the YouTube app, you can use try the examples in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114341/force-video-to-open-in-youtube-app-on-android) post, or explore the [YouTubePlayer API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/).

Comment: Thanks alot my friend